# Want to print numbers in details section of my crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report i want to print the numbers in detail section like this .......
1        2       3    4     5    6     7    8   9     10
11       12      13   14    16   16    17   18  19    20

In this I will pass Starting Number and Last Number.
In given example starting number is 1 and last number is 20.
This is possible or not  ???

Comment: Where do you want the numbers to be printed to?

Comment: In crystal report's detail section

Answer (score 1):

Create a formula `@Count` place it in `page header` or `Report header`.

```
Shared NumberVar i;
i:=0;
```

Create a formula `@Display` and place it in detail.

```
Shared NumberVar i;

i:=i+1;
i;
```

Comment: Showing error in @Display formula field while saving

Comment: try now change the answer... there was a typo error

Comment: print only one row in detail section

Comment: explain more what is `print only one row in detail section `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have two parameters: `{?start}` and `{?end}`, create a formula:

```
// {@generate}

Local Stringvar Array values;
Local Numbervar i;

for i:= {?start} to {?end} do (
  Redim Preserve values[Ubound(values)+1];
  values[Ubound(values)]:=ToNumber(i,"#")
);

Join(values);
```